# use of String.matches(regex) in smartgwt

Tags: regex, smartgwt

I am working with smartgwt since three months.
I have encountered a problem with the specific method of the string class.

It seems that the matches never works, even with the simplest one:

```
String regex = "CEDD";
String input = "CEDD";
input.matches(regex);
```

this will always returns false. Such piece of code is within a class extending the smartgwt Layout class, and therefore got converted to js and used in front end.
The same fragment obviously works when used in a simple java main standalone class.

Could you point out what to investigate to solve this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [GWT doesn't support normal Java regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162240/regular-expressions-and-gwt) (i.e. doesn't support `Pattern`, `Matcher` and classes/methods that use it.

There is a [`RegExp` class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html) that provides those features, however.

Comment: One other possible solution, altough a bit weird, is to write a native method and write javascript regex in it.