# Validate a textField with GXT

Tags: regex, gwt, gxt

I have to check some textField with the following regex:

```
[\sa-zA-Z.'-àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]+
```

It works with regex checkers but it doesn't work with my GWT/GXT application. I use the function above in a class that extends AbstractValidator.

```
public static native boolean isValidName(String name) /*-{
    var pattern =  /[\sa-zA-Z.\'-àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]+/;
    return pattern.test(name);
}-*/;
```

I use GXT2 and GWT 1.6.4.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried using `String.macthes` for validate the value and `Validator` class in gxt `TextField`?

```
    someTextField.setValidator(new Validator() {
        @Override
        public String validate(Field<?> field, String value) {
            return value.matches("[\\sa-zA-Z.'-àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]+") 
                                 ? null : "not a valid value";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK for gxt2...

the corresponding method is [setRegex(String regex)](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/extjs/gxt/2.2.0/gxt-2.2.0-javadoc.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/TextField.html#setRegex%28java.lang.String%29) which will get called if all other validators have passed

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/extjs/gxt/2.2.0/gxt-2.2.0-javadoc.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/TextField.html

Why don't you use (for gxt3):

```
 com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.Field<T>.addValidator(Validator<T> validator) 

 field.addValidator(new RegExValidator( "[\sa-zA-Z.\'-àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]", "some message"));
```

see [gxt field api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/Field.html#addValidator%28com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.Validator%29)

see [gxt RegExValidator](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/validator/RegExValidator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why go native, while you can still use `Java` ? Or even better, try to see if `GXT` gives you some validation tools. Like `Validators`

*Related :* [Regular Expressions and GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162240/regular-expressions-and-gwt)

Comment: @MacFly Did you check the link I've posted ?

Comment: @MacFly I strongly suggest you to add GWT and GXT version to your question... However, I can't help you on this, I know GWT since 2.1. Maybe you should consider updating GWT ?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha GXT4:

enum VType

---

```
 public enum VType {
    ALPHABET("^[a-zA-Z_]+$", "Alphabet"), ALPHANUMERIC("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$",
            "Alphanumeric"), NUMERIC("^[+0-9]+$", "Numeric"), EMAIL("^(\\w+)([-+.][\\w]+)*@(\\w[-\\w]*\\.){1,5}([A-Za-z]){2,4}$","Email");
    String regex;
    String name;

    VType(String regex, String name) {
        this.regex = regex;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Validator class

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.editor.client.Editor;
import com.google.gwt.editor.client.EditorError;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.Validator;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.error.DefaultEditorError;

public class VTypeValidator implements Validator<String> {

    private String message;  
    private final VType type;

    public VTypeValidator(VType type,String message){
      this.type = type;
      this.message=message;
    }



  @Override
  public List<EditorError> validate(Editor<String> editor, String value) {
      List<EditorError> res = null;
      if (!value.matches(type.regex)) {
          List<EditorError> errors = new ArrayList<EditorError>();
          errors.add(new DefaultEditorError(editor, message,""));
          return errors;
        }
      return res;
  }
}
```

How to use with textField

---

```
   field.addValidator(new VTypeValidator(VType.EMAIL,"Invalid email"));
```

Comment: Reference:https://biancama.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/gwt-gxt-using-client-validation/