# Prevent characters to be typed in base on regex

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I have a regex to allow only numbers, numbers with dot and comma, if user inputs character that breaks the regex it should not be typed in:

```
valueTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                String input = valueTextBox.getText();
                if (!input.matches("\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?")) {
                }
            }
        });
```

For example, I typed 123 initially, then type a dot that should be ok, and I type a number to complete it like 123.123 should be ok, if I type a comma now that should not be ok.

Comment: how about `event.consume();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DomEvent#preventDefault](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#preventDefault%28%29) that prevents the wrapped native event's default action.

Use [GWT RegExp](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html) for GWT client side regex.

---

Read more about [Differences between JRE and emulated classes](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html#differences)

Find more samples on [Regular Expressions and GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162240/regular-expressions-and-gwt)